# My double variable has got 2 values? Java

Tags: java

I'll keep it short. I've got this basic java code:

```
int listLength = sc.nextInt();
double[] list = new double[listLength];

for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   list[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

When I input 1 12345678901234567
Now if I execute this line:
`System.out.println(list[0] == 12345678901234568.0 && list[0] == 12345678901234567.0);`

The console will print: true

If I just print list[0], it prints 12345678901234568

I ask the console to print if a double value is 2 different numbers and it says it's true.
How is this possible?

Comment: Numbers in computer hardware have a finite number of bits.  For floating-point numbers, this translates into a fixed precision.  For Java **double** this is 15 decimal digits.

Comment: Those aren't two values; they are the same value. `12345678901234568.0 == 12345678901234567.0` is `true` - you can confirm for yourself.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004).

Comment: `12345678901234568` in binary is `101011110111000101010001011101011010110100101110001000`, which has three zero bits at the RHS, so it only uses 53 bits when normalized. `12345678901234567` in binary is `101011110111000101010001011101011010110100101110000111`, which needs the three extra bits, and they are not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java double-precision float can store between 15-16 digits before the decimal point in the number because that's what the IEEE 754 floating-point standard allows for the maximum integer part. Your number is 17 digits. Try the same test after rounding/truncating a few digits off and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not all numbers can be represented exactly with a `double`, because there are infinitely many numbers, and only finitely many `double` values.  If you try to store a number in a `double`, and there's no `double` value that represents it exactly, you'll get the nearest (or nearest equal) value that *can* be represented.

In your particular case, 12345678901234567 can't be represented exactly with a `double`, so whenever you write `12345678901234567.0`, the `double` that's actually stored is the nearest (or nearest equal) available one, which is the one representing `12345678901234568`.